# Adding a persistent footer underneath a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I've inherited a project for which I want to add a persistent footer area beneath the entire app. The app is using a `UITabBarController` that is always shown other than for a login screen. The `tabBarController` is created as follows:

```
   UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
   UIStoryboard *sb1 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SB1" bundle:nil];
   // ... same for sb2 and sb3

   [tabBarController setViewControllers:@[sb1, sb2, sb3]];
   [tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

I've tried manually setting `tabBarController.size.height`, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I've never used `storyboards` before, is there some way to do `initWithFrame` when using them? Or am I approaching this completely the wrong way?

Comment: You can embed tab-bar view controller into another view controller. This way you'll be able to resize and move the tab-bar view controller and add something below the tab-bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks werediver, you got me on the right track. I got it working by adding the UITabBarController as a child view controller and then manually adding its view as well.

```
const CGFloat FOOTER_HEIGHT = 20;

// Set up tab bar area
CGRect contentFrame = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.frame;
contentFrame.size.height -= FOOTER_HEIGHT;                       
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.view.frame = contentFrame;

// Set up footer
CGRect footerFrame = contentFrame;
footerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
footerFrame.size.height = FOOTER_HEIGHT;
UIView *footer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:footerFrame];

// Create outer view controller
UIViewController *outer = [[UIViewController alloc] init];                               
[outer addChildViewController:tabBarController];
[outer.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[outer.view footer];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController = outer;
```